# Problems with table name in WP

Tags: database, wordpress

I'm trying to insert values in a database from Wordpress. The table name is "wp-consultte", this is the way i call it: $wpdb->insert('wp-consultte'....

Using the WP debug "$wpdb->show_errors();" this appeared: WordPress database error: [Table 'wordpress.wp-consultte' doesn't exist]

I don't understand why WP try to find 'wordpress.wp-consultte' when the database name is 'wp-consultte'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why insert doesn't work but you can always fall back on

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO 'wp-consultte' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `wordpress.wp-consultte` refers to the wp-consultte **table** in the wordpress **database**. Therefore it is searching in the right place.

You have to create your table first in the database. Based on your previous question: [Problems using database from Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105114/problems-using-database-from-wordpress) I assume it doesn't exist yet.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Create_Database_Tables would be a good start.